# retrieve the right rows in linq with a list inside of a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, c#-4.0

I have a table and inside of that table I have a List.

I'm trying to retrieve from the table only the rows that don't have "Hello" in the list,

example,

I have 3 rows, and for each row I have three row in the List with different values, so how can I retrieve only the one that don't have the word "hello"
this is what I was trying to do

```
IQueryable<table> _table = tab.AsQueryable();
var retrieve=_table.Where(x=>(x.list.Where(y=>!y.Name.Equal("Hello"))).Any());
```

But this returns by each line of the list, and I want to search in all of the row that the list have and then only return if there isn't "Hello" in any.

Answer (score 0):

```
var retrieve=_table.Where(x => !x.list.Any(y => y.Name.Equal("Hello")));
```